# In Xamarin XAML, how do I set a Constraint on a RelativeLayout using a Style?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am struggling to work out the XAML syntax to apply constraints to a `RelativeLayout` using a `Style`.

The first piece of Xamarin XAML below shows a pair of nested `RelativeLayout` elements used to construct a simple layout (the inner element simply puts a margin around an area to which I can add other content).  This version of the code builds and runs fine on iOS and Android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Page1">
    <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Maroon"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.9,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.9,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.05,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.05,Constant=0}">
            <BoxView Color="Yellow"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

What I would like to do it use the same layout on multiple pages, so I want to put the `RelativeLayout` constraints into a `Style`.  This second piece of code does not parse or run, but I hope it shows what I am trying to achieve.  If I can get the right syntax for this, the idea is that the `Style` can then be moved out into a shared file, so I can easily re-use it across multiple instances of `ContentPage`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Page2">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="LayoutStyle" TargetType="RelativeLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Maroon"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightConstraint">
                    <Setter.Value>"Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.9,Constant=0"</Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="WidthConstraint">
                    <Setter.Value>"Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.9,Constant=0"</Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="YConstraint">
                    <Setter.Value>"Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.05,Constant=0</Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="XConstraint">
                    <Setter.Value>"Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.05,Constant=0</Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <RelativeLayout Style="LayoutStyle">
            <BoxView Color="Yellow"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.25,Constant=0}"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Please can anyone help me out with the syntax for doing this?

This is a link to a complete example (which obviously requires Xamarin to be installed and needs the nuget packages to be restored): [XAML Layout Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz__vXtiMe03bTFTb3owaWtfV00/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="LayoutStyle" TargetType="RelativeLayout">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Maroon"/>
        <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint" Value="{ConstraintExpression RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.9,Constant=0}"/>
        <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint" Value="{ConstraintExpression RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.9,Constant=0}"/>
        <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.YConstraint" Value="{ConstraintExpression RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.05,Constant=0}"/>
        <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.XConstraint" Value="{ConstraintExpression RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.05,Constant=0}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does indeed build and run; however, I think there may be a bug in the Xamarin layout model because I get inconsistent behaviour when I move the constraint into a Style.  It's not like CSS, is it, whereby moving the rule into a Style lowers its score in the algorithm that decides what to apply?  I am going to raise it as a bug with Xamarin.

Comment: It is possible to override properties set in a Style by providing a different setting inline on the element, but the rules are much simpler than with CSS. However Xamarin.Forms is fairly sensitive to not specifying enough information for layout, which manifests as inconsistent behavior. Since this answer addresses the original question, please mark it as accepted answer. To figure out what's going on with the layout, aside from filing a bug with Xamarin, you could also ask another question with screenshots of the two versions of your page.

Comment: My mistake. I could kick myself.  When trying to apply the Style as shown above, I forgot to put the '{StaticResource...}' in the specifier.  So, to be 100% clear, the answer by @DavidS is completely correct and works perfectly.  Thank you again.